# NAT through a VPN

Tags: iptables, openvpn, nat

I am stuck to reach a server behind a VPN client.

I want to be able to contact 10.0.0.200:1521 from 192.168.1.6.

[image: network]

I configured the VPN access and can ping 192.168.27.65 (Debian) from 192.168.1.6 (Ubuntu).

On the Debian, I can ping 10.0.0.200 with 10.1.0.51.

I have set NAT on 192.168.1.6 for requests going to 10.0.0.200:1521, to 192.168.27.65:65000 **(1)** with the following rules :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.200 -p tcp --dport 1521 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.27.65:65000;
```

I tried to route 192.168.27.65:65000 (tun0) to 10.1.0.51:65000 (eth0) **(2)** but didn't succeed.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 65000 -j ACCEPT;

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 65000 -j ACCEPT;

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.27.65 -p tcp --dport 65000 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.0.51:65000;
```

Thus, I can't test the last rule to route 10.1.0.51:65000 to 10.0.0.200:1521 **(3)**.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.1.0.51 -p tcp --dport 65000 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.200:1521;

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;
```

How to reach 10.0.0.200:1521 from 192.168.1.6?

I think I'm wrong on the point 192.168.27.65:65000 (tun0) can't reach 10.1.0.51:65000 and I should do NAT between tun0 and eth0 instead of using IPs but I don't know how to do that.

On a previous configuration, I used the following to route traffic to localhost:port and then route localhost:port to another host. But here it is a bit more complicated.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.200 -p tcp --dport 1521 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:65000
```

[image: network2]

Answer (score 0):

As temp workaround you could try this on the debian machine:

iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p TCP -s 192.168.1.6/32 -d 10.0.0.200/32 --dport 1521 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.1.0.51

as long as the 192.168.1.6 host or the router know how to route the packets to the debian host. the debian host will then rewrite the source to its own ip and routes the packets to the 10.0.0.200:1521 server. So the Server 10.0.0.200:1521 will only see connections from the IP 10.1.0.51 instead of the real origin 192.168.1.6

Edit: One more thing. Is forwarding enabled on the debian machine?
check with: cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
result should be a 1